# Derivative at discontinuous

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Consider $f(x) = \sqrt{|x|}$ for $x\in[-10,10]$.
[image]

With derivative $f'(x) = \frac{\text{sign}(x)}{2\sqrt{|x|}}$
[image].

- Is it true that $f'(0) = \infty \wedge f'(0)=-\infty$ holds at the same time?
- How would you express that statement formally?

Comment: $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are not numbers. $f'(0)$ does not exist.

Comment: @mrf 's comment should be in the Answer box, cuz that's the answer.

Comment: Is the following statement  $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)=-\infty$ true then?

Comment: No, rather $\lim_{x\to0^-}f'(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to0^+}f'(x)=+\infty$.

Comment: Is this correct? I thought for the right hand limit we move from right to left and thus the function decreases?!

Answer (score 0):

One could say that $f'(0)$ does not exist as usually left- and right limits defining the derivative are required to exist and to be the same to assign the derivative a value.

Alternatively one could introduce a concept similar to [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), but the dirac delta function as here only allows a discontinuty of a certain "gap size". The gap we have in our so our problem is infinite length (from $-\infty \to \infty$) so we would need to do it in some fancier way though.

Comment: the distributional derivative exists always. here, it just hasn't a representative which is continuous at $0$.